# Injection error while injecting scope in custom filter definition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am trying to inject a $scope variable in a angularjs custom filter definition.

The javascript code looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
 .filter("MyFilter", ['$scope', MyFilterFunction])

function MyFilterFunction($scope){
 return function(client){
   return client.toLowerCase();
 }
}
```

But this way it is not working due to injection error. Is there any better way to achieve what I am trying to do here.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You cannot inject `scope` because there is no `scopeService` or `scopeProvider`. However you can inject `$rootScopeProvider`. But in a filter you would almost never need it. Only controllers and directive can have reference to scope object. However you can have filter take multiple arguments if that is what your actual motive is. you can do `return function(input,arg1,arg2,..)` and use it as "somedata | myFilter:data1:data2..."

Comment: Thanks for the reply PSL. I am trying to access a object stored in scope variable. But it seems that scope is not available then I left with the option to achieve the same with the help of parameters. But I have a good question that what is the rationale behind limiting the scope reference to controllers and directives only.

Comment: filter is a singleton like the providers, services etc.. What is the meaning of scope there (and what is the scope)? unlike controllers.